# Empty std::ios::openmode?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I have base class with a function `virtual std::ios::openmode defaultMode() const`.

What would be the syntax of this function if I want : `(defaultMode() | mode) == mode`, where mode is another `std::ios::openmode` ? How to return an "empty" `std::ios::mode` that will not modify the other modes?

Comment: IMHO it makes no sense for an openmode to be empty, but whatever. Since it's an integer type, `0` should work.

Comment: @Vincent - If the type has an empty/default value, you can generally get that by using a constructor-like `std::ios::openmode()`.